# User denied access to file stored in sharepoint from SSRS link

Tags: excel, pdf, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a set of SSRS reports on Sharepoint via which users can access several Excel / PDF files and can also export reports to Excel / PDF. One of the users has contacted me to say that when the SSRS action links directly to a file he gets an error message saying:

Error: Access Denied
Current User
You are currently signed in as: *********

He has said that he is able to export other reports to Excel and PDF, and that the problem only occurs when the report goes straight to a file. As far as we both can see the user has full permissions.

Can anyone help with why this may be?

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I see unauthorized errors when the user tries to open a link and it opens with Chrome/Firefox since those don't properly pass the AD authentication to SharePoint.  Could this be the problem in your case?

Also I'm not sure how you are checking the permissions, but navigate to the file in question and "Check Permissions" from the dropdown menu to emulate for that specific user.